# Maximum energy transfer in Compton process

Tags: photons, scattering

Consider a gamma ray incident on an electron at rest with wavelength $\lambda$, in a Compton scattering process . What is the maximumc kinetic energy the electron can gain from this? Can the gamma ray be fully absorbed, or is this not possible in Compton scattering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum kinetic energy of the electron occurs when the change in wavelength of the photon is a maximum.
The formula for wavelength change is usually given in terms of the cosine of the scattering angle of the photon.
So you can decide which scattering angle gives you the maximum change in wavelength and hence the maximum KE gain of the electron.

Once you have done this you can answer your last question.